# Numerate SQL column values and pick a random one

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I will not lie, but I have no clue on how can I do it, I am using PHP and SQL, have some values in one SQL table for example:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| ID | username | presentid |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | user1    |         1 |
|  2 | user2    |         1 |
|  3 | user1    |         2 |
|  4 | user2    |         2 |
|  6 | user3    |         2 |
|  7 | user4    |         1 |
|  8 | user6    |         1 |
|  9 | user7    |         1 |
| 10 | user13   |         1 |
| 11 | user11   |         2 |
| 12 | user14   |         2 |
| 13 | user9    |         1 |
| 14 | user15   |         1 |
| 15 | user5    |         2 |
| 16 | user5    |         1 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Where `username` is the account username and the `presentid` is the present "raffle".

What I need is something that would get the values in order, for example, get all users that joined present one:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| ID | username | presentid |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | user1    |         1 |
|  2 | user2    |         1 |
|  7 | user4    |         1 |
|  8 | user6    |         1 |
|  9 | user7    |         1 |
| 10 | user13   |         1 |
| 13 | user9    |         1 |
| 14 | user15   |         1 |
| 16 | user5    |         1 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

So in order by joined all of them should have one specific number all the time for example in the case above it would be like:

```
1 = user1
2 = user2
3 = user4
4 = user6
5 = user7
6 = user13
7 = user9
8 = user15
9 = user5
```

This order should be unique since it is the order they joined the present raffle and I would like to show in the PHP page the users in that order with the number, then I would like to use that order and pick a random number from 1 to 9 since only 9 users joined.

Is it possible? If yes can someone give me some help please I want to do it with PHP.

I really need to have one idea on how I can do that, ordering the users like that.

With the code provided by @Babydead:

```
    $querythis = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `users_giveaways` WHERE `presentid`= 1');
    $results = $querythis->fetch();


    $presentGroups = array();
    foreach($results as $r){

      $presentID = $r['presentid'];
      $userID = $r['username'];

  $presentGroups[$presentID][] = $userID;

      $string=implode(",",$results);
        echo $string;
    }
    foreach($presentGroups as $presentID => $usersArray){
      $arrayLength = (count($usersArray));

      $randomNumber = mt_rand(1, $arrayLength) - 1;

      echo $usersArray[$randomNumber] . "has been selected for $presentID !!! <br/><br/>";
    }
```

I am getting this results:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'username'...
```

and

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'presentid'...
```

But I have those columns.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: If you want to order them by when they joined, you should have a timestamp column, and a trigger to set it's value when the row is added. You can use the ID (if it's auto-increment) for this purpose as well. Show your schema and any SQL statements you've tried.

Comment: What is the schema of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so first, you get all the results from a `MYSQL` query, I assume you know how that works (otherwise just ask :))

Now, on PHP, you can split the present ID's and user ID's into groups like so:

### example:

```
$presentGroups = array();
//Loop through query results
foreach($results as $r){

  $presentID = $r['presentid']
  $userID = $r['username']
  //Put the users in sub-arrays by presentID
  $presentGroups[$presentID][] = $userID;
}
```

now, you can just grab a random user out of the array and voila; an automated raffle.

```
//Let's get some results going.
//Get the presentID's (key of created array) and the users coupled with it
foreach($presentGroups as $presentID => $usersArray){
  //Get the length of the current array for the random number generator
  $arrayLength = (count($usersArray));

  //Generate random number
  $randomNumber = mt_rand(1, $arrayLength)) - 1;

  //Grab any array index through the generated random number
  echo $usersArray[$randomNumber] . "has been selected for $presentID !!! <br/><br/>";
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should be somewhat like this, no?

Comment: I am getting the following warning:  `Warning: Illegal string offset` in `presentID` and `userID`, and it's always giving the same number the number 1, I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Well I can't really test the code, sorry... Anyway, it says those are illegal offsets because they don't exist. They should be `username ` and `presentid` according to your own post, sorry.

Comment: They exist, also have updated my question, and thanks for being here trying to help me out.

Comment: what is `$querythis->fetch();` ? This seems wrong to me since you run the query through the `$db` variable... Have you used `var_dump($results);` yet, to see if the query actually works? also, I feel as if you should use `$querythis` in the foreach loop instead of `$results`.

Comment: Nevermind found the problem -.- it was the table name you had reason :D

Comment: and now I am using the $querythis and it's working, is there any way to check if the array order is always the same?

Comment: Found a way I can use `print_r`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, I left the array order for what it is... Instead of shuffling the array through shuffle (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), I just use the random number generator to grab a random array item... If you use `print_r` (or `var_dump`) you should print the `$randomNumber`, not the array :) -- The best is to print_r everything, just so you know what happens when